# bash html automation scripts running at once

Tags: html, linux, bash, cat

i'm attempting to use bash scripts to create a web page, have no issue doing that at all. The problem is I need to get each part of the site to be added individually e.g the first file (main.html) needs to have navigation and content added which are separate scripts. My problem is trying to get them to run all at once using the command line.

I tried:

```
cat main.html | navigation
```

and even tried adding it to a new file e.g

```
cat main.html | navigation > mainnew.html
```

I've tried adding the file extension to navigation, but i'm a little unsure how that affects it as it doesn't seem to work no matter what file type it is (.sh/.html/.txt).

Any direction you can point me in would help.

thanks

Comment: Interesting, `navigation` parses the input and adds stuff at the proper places?

Comment: I've not been able to get it to work, so i have absolutely no idea.

Comment: What exactly is `navigation` then? Not a script?

Comment: Can you share what the program navigation does? or its full bash script?

Comment: just figured it out thanks, i was just completely not thinking. Lack of sleep isn't fun.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! I figured it out.

```
cat main.html | navigation > mainnew.html
```

should be

```
cat main.html navigation.html > mainnew.html
```